# Como usar DataTable Plugin (Jquery) com o Node.js

Tags: node.js, jquery-datatables, express.js, ejs

Estou trabalhando com node e express e preciso preencher uma tabela com informações que vem de um Banco SQL.
Executo meu código no get da página desse modo:

```
app.get('/Home.ejs', (req, resp) => {
    SQL_Server(Seleciona, (rec) => {
        resp.render("Home", { Objeto: rec });
        resp.end();
    });
});
```

Ele estava dando certo quando eu carregava a tabel assim:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < Objeto.length; i++){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td name="Nome">
                            <%=Objeto[i].ObjetoNome %>
                        </td>
                        <td name="Nome">
                                <%=Objeto[i].ObjetoEndereco %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
<%}%>
```

Mas agora eu preciso encher essa tabela usando JQuery, pois estamos padronizando os templates de todos os sistemas.
Quando tentei usar o dataTable do jquery, ele não está mais exibindo a tabela. Eis o meu código:

```
var TableDados = $('#MinhaTabela').DataTable({
                "serverSide": true,
                ajax: {
                    "url": "/Home.ejs",
                    "dataSrc": "Objeto"
                }, 
                "scrollX": true,
                "processing": true,
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "deferRender": true,
                "language":
                {
                    "url": "<% /scripts/plugins / dataTables / languagePT - BR.json' %>"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Nome" },
                    { "data": "Endereço" },
                ],
                "order": [0, "asc"]
            });
```

Ele não abre mais a tela e exibe a mensagem:

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)

Pesquisei diversas soluções e exemplos mas continua exibindo esse erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a devida solução.

```
<script>
//Atribui a variável Lista o array de objetos que retorna do backend
var Lista= <%- JSON.stringify(lista) %>;

var TableDados = null;
$(function () {

    TableDados = $('#tblDados').DataTable({
        "serverSide": false,
        "drawCallback": function (settings) {},
        "scrollX": true,
        "processing": true,
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "language":
        {
            "url": "/scripts/plugins/dataTables/languagePT-BR.json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Nome" },
            { "data": "Sobrenome" },
            { "data": "Numero" },
            { "data": "Idade" },
        ],
        "order": [0, "asc"]
    });
    console.log(Lista);
    TableDados.rows.add(Lista)
    TableDados.draw();
});
```